# Running selenium Scripts on remote machine(VM) from Azure Continuous Integration Pipeline

Tags: python, azure, selenium, devops

I have written selenium testcase using python, Now I want to Integrate my selenium testcase code with Azure-DevOps Pipeline. We want to create CI/CD pipeline which will trigger my selenium code & automatically run the selenium testcase & also show the testcase running on chrome or other browers. & How we can run our selenium test case on  remote machine(Virtual Machine from Azure Continuous Integration Pipeline.

We are trying to connect with Remote machine from Azure Continuous Integration Pipeline using powershell on Target machine, we have enabled WinRM & also Created Trusted Host. but Unable to connect to remote machine.

we are getting some error like...

2021-12-15T18:21:18.0014919Z ##[error]Unable to create pssession. Error: 'Connecting to remote server 52.152.164.244 failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.'

2021-12-15T18:21:39.6640758Z ##[error]The remote session query failed for 52.152.164.244 with the following error message: WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet.

[image: Screenshot of error message]

Comment: Could you please make sure that `WinRM` is enabled in both local and remote computers by running this cmd as administrator : `winrm quickconfig`

Comment: It is enabled in remote machine which is Virtual machine, & I want to connect azure devOps pipeline with Remote machine. So there is need to enable WinRM in my local asset?

Comment: Could you please try to enable in your local asset and let me know if still facing the same

Comment: My another question is there any solution to run the python selenium testcase on local or Remote machine with Azure Continous integration & Continous deployment pipeline. So that after triggering that code it will open the browser & show the test is running

Comment: Ok I will enable that & what to add in trusted host in my local system? We need to get & set trusted host?.

Comment: Could you please refer this https://serverfault.com/questions/1002098/winrm-will-not-connect-to-remote-computer-in-my-domain